# Another why was this one moved to x and not y

Tags: discussion

Just curious why was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995437/how-do-you-do-wildcard-subdomains) moved to SU instead of SF? I am trying to pick up on all the little things of the community and that has me stumped.

> - networking, servers, or maintaining other people's PCs and contains no source code, ask on Server Fault.

This question was clearly about servers and not about

> - general computer software or hardware troubleshooting

Comment: Murphy says it will get migrated from SU to SF, edited/clarified to be programming related, and wind up back on SO.

Comment: Especially since .htaccess verges on programming at its more complex extremes.

Comment: The question has been migrated to SF. However it will not show this on the banner. I have edited the question to indicate the transfer

Comment: thanks, Diago.  here's the new link (the original SF & SU links are now dead): http://serverfault.com/questions/99050/how-do-you-do-wildcard-subdomains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is pretty solidly an SF question.  I don't doubt there's the capability on SU to answer it (heck, there were 3 answers on it when it was migrated, so SO has the capability to answer it too), but to me it reads like an SF question.

The migrations happen automatically when 5 users vote to close, and the migration destination is chosen like the other close reasons -- by whatever option got a the majority of those 5 close votes.  In this case, at least two people voted for "migrate to SU" (it's possible the other 3 votes were for each of 3 other close/migrate options.  So the 2-vote majority won.  And as I understand it, ties go to the oldest vote, so it might've been 2 votes for SU, 2 for SF, 1 for something else... but it went to SU because the oldest of the 4 migrate votes was for SU.)  So it's a bit of a majority-rule-and-the-majority-makes-stupid-decisions-sometimes situation.

I wonder if migration-due-to-close-votes shouldn't be sent into a kind of migration queue, where some high-rep volunteer looks at it in order to route it to the proper site.  There'd be only one "migrate" option on the vote-to-close menu, so the migrate votes wouldn't be competing with each other to determine the proper site.  (Or maybe a secondary vote would be cast -- vote to migrate, then get to vote for which site it should go on.  A bit like the close-as-duplicate option works now.)  But the final step should be a human picking one of the trilogy sites to send it to (possibly even "stay here").

Comment: I like the idea of the queue even tho I know they wouldn't implement it due to it causes more paths in the way of a question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right, that Server Fault is a better place for this question. But it is one of those questions which is suitable for both communities. Super User has also a `htaccess` tag. Only a few questions there, but they got answers. So it's likely that the asker finds help on SU, too.

You could comment his post and advice him to search on SF for an answer also. Would be helpful for him at least for the next time, he asks a question :)